# image upload working on localhost fine but not in server in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

Image upload working on localhost fine using request.getRealPath() but same we are using in server that's not

working, because server can not find specified path.. image can't be displayed .. how i can solved this problem.??

here is code for image uploading:

```
           filePath =request.getRealPath("") + "\\img\\";                 
            System.out.println(filePath);
        String contentType = request.getContentType();

        if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) 
        {
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
                   //  message=    fileItems.get(2).toString();



            Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
                                 if(fi.isFormField())
                                 {
                                     message=fi.getString();
                                     System.out.println("message is  : "+message);
                                     bean.setEmp_id(Integer.parseInt(message));
                                 }
                if (!fi.isFormField()) {
                    String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                    System.out.println("field name"+fieldName);
                    fileName = fi.getName();




                    if (fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0) {
                        file = new File(filePath
                                + fileName.substring(fileName
                                        .lastIndexOf("\\")));

                    } else {
                        file = new File(filePath
                                + fileName.substring(fileName
                                        .lastIndexOf("\\") + 1));

                    }
                    fi.write(file);
```

Comment: Can you please show the codes ? and the paths you are getting in local and at run time ?

Comment: in localhost image is uploaded to following path:E:\CRM\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CRM\img

Comment: i use  org.apache.commons.fileupload library for image uploading

Comment: check if the file is saved in the server after uploading it

Comment: image is not uploaded

Comment: but i cant find the reason of not uploading image because same code work fine on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getRealPath()` gives the absolute path (on the file system) leading to a file specified in the parameters of the call. It returns the path in the format specific to the OS.

Read [`request#getRealPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String))for its documentation.

Also it is advised to use `servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` instead of `servletRequest.getRealPath("/")` as it is deprecated.

so the best way is to provide the `upload path` for the server by yourself, as the method values specific to the OS the returned path may not be accessible(Permissions).

Hope this helps !!

Comment: thank you very much for help.i get idea about what is problem.